# How can I download the result page of Naver Search?

Tags: python, search, header, wget

I tried to download the result page of Naver Search.
But, It didn't work.

```
import os

url='https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=nexearch&ie=utf8&sm=tab_etc&os=3181371&pkid=59&query=%ED%95%B4%ED%94%BC%ED%88%AC%EA%B2%8C%EB%8D%94%20429%ED%9A%8C'

header='http://naver.com'

wget_cmd = 'wget -O a.txt --header="Referer: '+header+'" "'+url+'"'

os.system(wget_cmd)
```

Comment: Please explain what error you get.

Comment: try using requests module instead of calling wget.

Comment: [Henk van Boeijen] Since I use the wget in the windows, the command pop-up windows was dissapeared so fast. So, I cannot see the error message.

Comment: [Pierre Michard] I don't know how to use the requests module. If you know the usage about requrests, please show me the examples.